# Sender name in "send HTML mail" rule

Tags: 7, rules, mimemail

I have a local site I am testing. I have PhPMailer installed which works fine to send plain text email with the Sender name populated properly.  However when I installed MimeMail and try to use the same rule, except using action send HTML mail, the Sender name no longer appears.  Any help would be great.

```
{ "rules_entityform_client_confirmation_email" : {
"LABEL" : "Entityform Client Confirmation Email",
"PLUGIN" : "rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"TAGS" : [ "entity_rules_entityform_submission" ],
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "mimemail" ],
"USES VARIABLES" : {
  "entity" : { "label" : "Entity", "type" : "entityform" },
  "continue" : { "label" : "Continue Rules", "type" : "boolean" }
},
"IF" : [
  { "user_has_role" : { "account" : [ "entity:user" ], "roles" : { "value" : { "4" : "4" } } } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Email to: [entity:user:mail]\r\nHi [entity:user],\r\nThanks for creating a new project\r\n" } },
  { "mimemail" : {
      "USING" : {
        "key" : [ "entity:entityform-id" ],
        "to" : [ "entity:user:mail" ],
        "from_name" : "[site:name]",
        "subject" : "New Project Created",
        "body" : "Hi [entity:user],\r\nThanks for creating a new project",
        "plaintext" : "Hi [entity:user],\r\nThanks for creating a new project",
        "language" : [ "" ]
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "send_status" : { "send_status" : "Send status" } }
    }
  }
],
"PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "continue" ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this variation of your rule (using the rules UI to import it in your site):

```
{ "rules_entityform_client_confirmation_email_pv" : {
"LABEL" : "Entityform Client Confirmation Email PV",
"PLUGIN" : "rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"TAGS" : [ "entity_rules_entityform_submission" ],
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "mimemail" ],
"USES VARIABLES" : {
  "entity" : { "label" : "Entity", "type" : "entityform" },
  "continue" : { "label" : "Continue Rules", "type" : "boolean" }
},
"IF" : [
  { "user_has_role" : { "account" : [ "entity:user" ], "roles" : { "value" : { "4" : "4" } } } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Email to: [entity:user:mail]\r\nHi [entity:user],\r\nThanks for creating a new project\r\n" } },
  { "mimemail" : {
      "USING" : {
        "key" : [ "entity:entityform-id" ],
        "to" : [ "entity:user:mail" ],
        "from_name" : "[site:name]",
        "from_mail" : "somebody@example.com",
        "subject" : "New Project Created",
        "body" : "Hi [entity:user],\r\nThanks for creating a new project",
        "plaintext" : "Hi [entity:user],\r\nThanks for creating a new project",
        "language" : [ "" ]
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "send_status" : { "send_status" : "Send status" } }
    }
  }
],
"PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "continue" ]
}
}
```

The only difference with your exported rule is the line with `from_mail` that is added (and a slightly different machine name of your rule). Adapt the eMail Id I used to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Pierre - I thought the rule was supposed to automatically pick up both the sender email and name from the sitewide name and address, but I guess not because this works :)

Comment: @SharonDankwardt merci for the update (and accept / +1). Yes rules can sometimes be a little bit tricky. But apart from that It's an amazing module! Next ( [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) ) question?

Comment: I'm sure I'll be back if I have more questions :) Thanks Pierre